# Django annotate count doesn't work always return 1

Tags: python, django, annotate

My models:

```
class PicKeyword(models.Model):
    """chat context collection

    """
    keyword = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Myfilter:

```
from django.db.models import Count
PicKeyword.objects.annotate(Count('keyword'))[0].keyword__count
```

The result always get 1

just like:

```
print(PicKeyword.objects.filter(keyword='hi').count()
```

show:
    3

```
PicKeyword.objects.filter(keyword='hi').annotate(Count('keyword'))[0].keyword__count
```

show:
    1

Is it because I use sqllite or my keyword type is Textfield?

Comment: You should use `.values` and `.order_by` on the keyword to force grouping, like `PicKeyword.objects.filter(keyword='hi').values('keyword').annotate(Count('keyword')).order_by('keyword')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying to annotate the count of keywords here,
`PicKeyword.objects.annotate(Count('keyword'))[0].keyword__count`
only works when you want to summarize the relationship between multiple objects. Since, you do not have any related objects to the `keyword` field the output is always 1 (it's own instance)

As the API docs for [queryset.annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) states,

> Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of query expressions. An expression may be a simple value, a reference to a field on the model (or any related models), or an aggregate expression (averages, sums, etc.) that has been computed over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet.

[Blog Model reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#queryset-model-example) for the Queryset.annotate example

Finally, If there are no relationships among objects and your aim is to just get the count of objects in your `PicKeyword` Model, the answers from @samba and @Willem are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and none of the answers worked for me.
I was able to get it working using the following syntax passing only 1 field as value (worked for me because I was trying to spot duplicates):

```
dups = PicKeyword.objects.values('keyword').annotate(Count('keyword')).filter(keyword__count__gt=1)
```

The following returns always an empty queryset, which Should NOT:

```
dups = PicKeyword.objects.values('keyword','id').annotate(Count('keyword')).filter(keyword__count__gt=1)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The following will show the exact count:

```
PicKeyword.objects.annotate(Count('keyword')).count()
```

Comment: what I don't understand is that 'keyword' needs to be a field on the model. But I'm accessing a 'comments' field that isn't defined on my model and which should be accessible with comments_set (the comments model has a field with a foreign key pointed to the other model I first mentioned), but the thing is it isn't. It's not accessible as 'comments_set' but it's accessible as 'comments'. How come?

Answer (score 0):

With a single table with no relation, you need to apply different logic for annotation.

It looks like that in terms of simple SQL queries:

Suppose you need to calculate the number of rows where the `user_email` field has the same value:

```sql
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(u.user_email_count, 0) AS user_email_count
FROM your_table_name c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_email, COUNT(*) AS user_email_count
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY user_email
) u ON c.user_email = u.user_email;
```

The same query in Django has the following form:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery, Value, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

subquery = YourModelName.objects.filter(
              user_email=OuterRef('user_email')
           ).values('user_email').annotate(
              user_email_count=Count('user_email')
           ).values('user_email_count')

queryset = models.YourModelName.objects.annotate(
    user_email_count=Coalesce(
        Subquery(subquery),
        Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Now, this query set has a new extra column named `user_email_count.` Any instance of your class (if you redefine a query set) will also have a new field, `user_email_cont.` You can refer to it in any function which accepts the instance of your model. Here is an example of how to add the column with the number of rows in DB with the same user_email in the Django admin panel (list view):

```py
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(models.YourModelName)
class YourModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Admin View of My Model
    """

    list_display = ['field1', 'field2', 'user_email_count_field']

    @admin.display(ordering='user_email_count')
    def user_email_count_field(self, model_instance: YourModelName):
        """
        Returns the number of rows with the same user_email
        """
   
        # Here, I return the value of this newly added field
        # for each instance of my model.
        return model_instance.user_email_count

    user_email_count.short_description = 'Saved_questions'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        """
        Adds annotation (extra column named user_email_count)
        """
        
        // The code above for redefining a queryset
        subquery = ...
        queryset = ...

        return queryset
```